# Building Router with Transparent Web Resource Cache

Tags: router, nat

Network Interface Configuration

```
192.168.0.0 Out 1(enp10s0f0) - Local 01(enp10s0f1)  192.168.10.0
                             - Local 02(enp10s0f2)
                             - Local 03(enp10s0f3)

59.27.1.128 Out 2(enp11s0f0) - Local 04(enp11s0f1)  192.168.11.0
                             - Local 05(enp11s0f2)
                             - Local 06(enp11s0f3)
```

There are 2 lines for out-bound. Each line share its outbound connection to Locals. Out 1 => Local 01~02, Out 2 => Local 03~04

So I made a script to configure iptables as following

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp10s0f0 -j MASQUERADE -s 192.168.10.0/24
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp11s0f0 -j MASQUERADE -s 192.168.11.0/24

iptables -A FORWARD -i enp10s0f0 -o enp10s0f1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp10s0f0 -o enp10s0f2 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp10s0f0 -o enp10s0f3 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp10s0f1 -o enp10s0f0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp10s0f2 -o enp10s0f0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp10s0f3 -o enp10s0f0 -j ACCEPT

iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i enp10s0f1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j TPROXY --on-ip 0.0.0.0 --on-port 8080 --tproxy-mark 0x1/0x1
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i enp10s0f2 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j TPROXY --on-ip 0.0.0.0 --on-port 8080 --tproxy-mark 0x1/0x1
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i enp10s0f3 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j TPROXY --on-ip 0.0.0.0 --on-port 8080 --tproxy-mark 0x1/0x1

iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i enp10s0f0 --source 192.168.10.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i enp10s0f0 --destination 192.168.10.0/24 -j ACCEPT

iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i enp10s0f0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 -j MARK --set-mark 0x1/0x1

ip rule add fwmark 0x1/0x1 table 2
ip route add local 0.0.0.0/0 dev lo table 2    
//Do this for enp11, too
```

But One of out-line, which is plugged later, doesn't work as expected.
(OS reconfigure the routing table after the line is plugged. So out-line first plugged only works. Second one not.)
Local-lines connected on another out-line works.

I guess it is caused by routing table... but I couldn't figure out the problem.

This is 'ip route' shows.

```
default via 59.27.1.129 dev enp11s0f0  proto static  metric 2   
default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp10s0f0  proto static  metric 100 
59.27.1.128/26 dev enp11s0f0  proto kernel  scope link  src 59.27.1.176  metric 2 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp11s0f0  scope link  metric 2 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp10s0f0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.22  metric 100 
192.168.10.0/24 dev enp10s0f1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.10.251  metric 100 
192.168.11.0/24 dev enp11s0f1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.11.251  metric 2 
222.118.178.36 via 59.27.1.129 dev enp11s0f0  proto dhcp  metric 2
```

Thank you.

Comment: "One of out-line, which is plugged later"... What do you mean? Also, your iptables rules mention `enp10s0f3` which isn't present in either the routing table or the network configuration diagram of yours. Please include all the relevant information so that others can understand your setup and what you are actually asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem of routing table.

Exactly the same one.
Ref. 
[NAT box with multiple internal and external interfaces](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209031/nat-box-with-multiple-internal-and-external-interfaces)

have to divide table and add rules for lookup based on IP.